# iOS push notification error code

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I used

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

to handle the exception occurs during push registration.

I would like to display customized messages for different errors.

So far I found people use **error.code** to determine the error type

For instance:

```
 error.code = 3010 // is for the iPhone Simulator

 error.code = 3000 // Failed to get token
```

I am wondering where does Apple document those error code, because I would like to cover all the error types

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier for you to query the `NSError` object for a localised explanation for the error and display that instead. It might save you some work, up to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to map the error with my customized message.